# SSRS: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'DateValue' of 'Public Function Day(DateValue As Date) As Integer'

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two days using DATEDIFF (). I use following code for this:

```
=DATEDIFF(DAY,CDate(Fields!Eingang_Kundenanfrage.Value),CDate(Fields!Ausgang_Angebot.Value))
```

Every time I try to save the report, I get this error message:

```
[BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'DateValue' of 'Public Function Day(DateValue As Date) As Integer'.
```

The DataSource is a SharePoint List and the Date is given in the following format: 23.05.2014 00:00:00 (DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM:SS).

I've googled for a working solution for a long time now, but I had no success.

Is there someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Before enter your date value convert it to date datatype.

```
select datediff(day,convert(date,'2014-05-28 16:07:54.647'),convert(date,'2014-05-29 16:07:54.647')) as DiffDay
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I tried the following:
=DateDiff(DAY,convert(date,Fields!Eingang_Kundenanfrage.Value),convert(date,Fields!Ausgang_Angebot.Value))

Comment: what is the value of=>CDate(Fields!Eingang_Kundenanfrage.Value)

Comment: The value of Fields!Eingang_Kundenanfrage.Value is the result of a query from a SharePoint List. For example "6/9/2014 12:00:00 AM".

Comment: check all parameter is passed correctly from visual studio

Comment: I do not use visual studio. I'm using the Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder.

Comment: Is that above example execute directly? Try to convert your date at the above format.

Comment: Now I've tried to convert the date into a new Field first using this: _=Format(Cdate(Fields!Ausgang_Angebot.Value),"MM/dd/yyyy")_
This is works without any problems. Then I tried to calculate with the field. But I get the same error :/